# Доступ к данным через 2 процесса

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-3.5, процесс, subprocess

**Заинтересовался заданием:**
создайте два процесса и организуйте им совместный доступ к данным из файла data.txt. 
Ваша задача вывести строки из data.txt используя два процесса не нарушив порядка строк.

**Вопросы:**

1. Правильно ли я понимаю концепцию: процесс != поток, нужно 2 скрипта которые бы поочередно читали строку за строкой и выводили бы их на экран, реализовать это через subprocess (PIPE) ?
2. Как вы поняли задачу?
3. Подтолкните куда копать и что читать...

Comment: Не обязательно PIPE, можно использовать модуль `multiprocessing` - он позволяет работать с процессами, как с потоками - код получится если не идентичный, то похожий.

Answer (score -1):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

def target(item):
    lock.acquire()
    print(item)
    lock.release()

def init(lc):
    global lock
    lock = lc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lc = Lock()  # не нарушив порядка строк
    file = open('data.txt')  # совместный доступ к данным из файла
    with Pool(processes=2, initializer=init, initargs=[lc]) as pool:  # два процесса
        pool.map(target, file)  # вывести строки
```

Comment: За наводку спасибо. Но в вашей реализации Lock() не решало проблему порядка строк. Как я понял (исправьте если не так), что блокировка создается в каждом из процессов, но они о друг друге как бы не в курсе) - синхронизации как таковой нет.

Comment: зачем гадать если можно прочесть [synchronization-between-processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes)